# accepts_nested_attributes_for not saving the child attribute to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes

My accepts_nested_attributes_for only saves the parent and not the child (nested) attributes.  This is many_to_many relationship between parent and child.

Problem: nothing happens and nothing is saved.  But on the page, I get this message:

```
utf8: "\xE2\x9C\x93"
authenticity_token: 9Pjxt7e5RRgWVGafRyMoDqBSqmtj/R2zBSiVxGGxFOI=
parent: !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
name: "Test"
gender: Male
children_attributes: !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
"0": !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
  email: 1234@testing.com
commit: Submit
```

From the msg on my terminal log, I think it's because the children_attributes never got saved as it was assigned a "0"?. This is the terminal msg:

```
Started POST "/parents" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-14 11:14:14 -0400
Processing by ParentsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9Pjxt7e5RRgWVGafRyMoDqBSqmtj/R2zBSiVxGGxFOI=", "parent"=>{"name"=>"123", "gender"=>"Male", "children_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"email"=>"1234@testing.com"}}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `children` WHERE (LOWER(`children`.`email`) = LOWER('1234@testing.com')) LIMIT 1
SQL (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Controller-

```
def new
  @parent = Parent.new
  @parent.children.build
end

def create
  @parent = Parent.new(params[:parent])
  if @parent.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Parent model -

```
attr_accessible :children_attributes
has_many :children, :through => :parent_child_relationships

accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
```

Child model -

```
has_many :parents, :through => :parent_child_relationships
validates :email, :name, :presence => true
```

Parent form view -

```
<%= form_for(@parent, new_parent_path) do |f| %>

<div>
  <%= f.label(:name) %></br>    
  <%= f.text_field(:name) %>
</div>  

<div>
  <%= f.label(:gender) %> <br/>
  <%= f.select(:gender, ['Male', 'Female']) %>
</div>

  <%= f.fields_for :children do |ff| %>

  <div>
    <%= ff.label(:email)%></br>
    <%= ff.text_field(:email)%>
  </div>

  <% end %>

  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are any unsuccessful validations for the children model

You can validate on create, using something like below

```
  validates_uniqueness_of  :xxxx, :on => :create
```

Comment: That was it.  I have some validations for when a user creates a child by itself (instead of through the nested association).  Is there a way to make those validations only valid upon creation of the child by itself and to ignore those validations when it is part of a nested attribute?  Thanks

Comment: I thought that by using the code @parent.children.build in the new, you are effectively creating the new child object?  I have other validates_presence of in my child model so even if I do, :on => create, wouldn't that still not make it pass the validation?  I cleared my validations for now so this is just for my own knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your validations on child model to :

```
validates :name, :presence => true
validates :email, :presence => true, :email => true
```

And see if that fixes it for you?

Comment: Thanks Kristian, it looks like because there are a bunch of other validations and has_many :through associations that it is blocking the save...