# Nested Object Won't Save [Rails 4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I am building a forum using Rails.

When you make a topic, it will have the Name and Description from the Topic Class, and Post Content from the Post class... (When you create a thread, you automatically create one post with the content)

Meaning:
For every Topic, you can have multiple posts
For every post, you must have ONE topic.

For some reason, when I create a topic, it saves inputs for the topic, but throws out the inputs for the Post Class.

I've looked around Stackoverflow and noticed a few similar questions, and tried many of the answers just to get errors or nothing changes. ([accepts_nested_attributes_for not saving the child attribute to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418901/accepts-nested-attributes-for-not-saving-the-child-attribute-to-the-database?rq=1),

**Models**

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :forum
    has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy  
    belongs_to :user

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base  
    belongs_to :topic  
end
```

**Controllers - Topic**

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_topic, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @topics = Topic.all
  end

  def new
    @topic = Topic.new
    responses = @topic.posts.build
  end

  def create  
    @topic = Topic.new(topic_params)

    if @topic.save 
      flash[:success] = "Topic Posted"
      redirect_to "/forums/#{@topic.forum_id}" 
    else  
      render :new  
    end   
  end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_topic
      @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def topic_params
      params.require(:topic).permit(:name, :description, :last_poster_id, :last_post_at, :forum_id,
        posts_attributes: [:id, :content] )
    end
end
```

**_Form**

```
<%= form_for(@topic) do |f| %>
  <% if params[:forum] %>
    <input type="hidden" 
    id="topic_forum_id" 
    name="topic[forum_id]" 
    value="<%= params[:forum] %>" />
  <% end %>  

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :responses do |p| %>

    <%= p.label :content %><br />
    <%= p.text_area :content %>

  <% end %>


  <%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: My first thought is that strong parameters is filtering out the dependent attributes. Try inserting this at the top of the create method to inspect the contents of the params: `render text: topic_params and return`.

Comment: {"name"=>"Test", "description"=>"Lets try again", "forum_id"=>"3"}

Yeah, it has not even touched this part: posts_attributes: [:id, :content]

Comment: In your view I see fields for :responses but not :posts. Are you sure you see a param called posts_attributes in params[:topic]?

Comment: I do see a param called posts_attributes in params[:topic]

However, I did change the field from :responses to :posts and it worked. Yep. I feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to davidfurber, I was able to figure out what was wrong. Here is the solution if anyone else has the same problem.

You don't need to assign @topic.posts.build to a variable. 
That being said, You don't need responses in the _form view. Instead, put :posts where :responses was.

**_Form**

```
<%= form_for(@topic) do |f| %>
  ... 
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :posts do |p| %>
    <%= p.label :content %><br />
    <%= p.text_area :content %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller - Topic**

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_topic, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def new
    @topic = Topic.new
    @topic.posts.build
  end

  def create  
    # render text: topic_params and return
    @topic = Topic.new(topic_params)

    if @topic.save 
      flash[:success] = "Topic Posted"
      redirect_to "/forums/#{@topic.forum_id}" 
    else  
      render :new  
    end   
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_topic
      @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def topic_params
      params.require(:topic).permit(:name, :description, :last_poster_id, :last_post_at, :forum_id,
        posts_attributes: [:id, :content] )
    end
end
```